# How can I save a date Value with format DD/MM/YYYY in mongoose schema as I get an error doing so "Cast to Date failed for value "31/07/2019""

Tags: node.js, date, mongoose

I have a model in mongoose called Object its schema looks like this :

```
const objectSchema = new Schema(
  {
    debit: {
      type: Float
    },
    trans_date: {
      type: Date
    },
    {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'last_updated' }
  }
);
```

When I try to save a transaction like :

```
let obj = {
   debit: 100.0,
   trans_date: "31/07/2019"
}
await ObjectModel.create(obj)
```

I am met with the error `Cast to Date failed for value "31/07/2019"`
Does mongoose not take a date with the format of DD/MM/YYYY, please I need help on this.

Comment: Convert it to a proper date format.

Comment: @ceejayoz and what is a proper date format?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format

Answer (score 1):

When I remember correctly mongoose is using the standard javascript constructor for a variable of type `Date`. I think your string can not be used for constructing a date. Here is the documentation for `Date()`:

[Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Either you have to change your string/date to another format or you just have to use the Date.now() format.

> The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds
>   elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

So you will basically just have a long number. Then you can choose the format on the client-side when showing the information to a user.

I hope I could solve your problem.